# What happened to line spacing?

Tags: discussion, support

In my desktop ([macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) MacBook Pro) and phone (iOS) the line spacing for posts seems to have changed and is now much harder to read. I've been puzzling over this for a while and thought it might be a bug on my end, but recently saw it on another machine. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try this userscript: https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/Compact-Line-Height/StackCompactLineHeight.user.js. It will revert the changes made.